# UILabel does not update each time with for loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uilabel

I'm trying to animate my label in my UICollectionViewCell. I want to go randomly through the array and set the label randomly 10 times and then it stops at a random string from my array.

The problem is, it goes through my array (debugged it with a simple NSLog) BUT the label setText isn't used till the last number of my loop and the label is then set.

Here is my code:

```
-(void)animate{

    long index;

    for(detail* cells in [[self col] visibleCells]){

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[self col] indexPathForCell:cells];

        if ([array count] >= 3) {
            index = 2 * indexPath.section + indexPath.row;
        }else{
            index = 1 * indexPath.section + indexPath.row;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            [[cells detailLabel] setText: [[array objectAtIndex:index] returnRandomOptie]];
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.10];
            NSLog(@"%i", i);
        }

    }
}
```

And here is my `returnRandomOptie` from my custom Cell class:

```
-(NSString *) returnRandomOptie {
    NSUInteger randomIndex;
    NSString *string;

    if ([opties count] != 0) {
        randomIndex = arc4random() % [opties count];
        string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [opties objectAtIndex:randomIndex]];
    }

    return string;
}
```

So basically I want that the for loop in my animate method, always sets the text in my label. And now it doesn't do that. Just at the last loop.

What am I doing wrong?

Kind Regards!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to perform the sleep async and update the label in the main thread, try this instead :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [[cells detailLabel] setText: [[array objectAtIndex:index] returnRandomOptie]];
        });
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.10];
        NSLog(@"%i", i);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey man thanks! This works. To bad it's a bit hard for me to know what's happening now. Didn't learned about dispatch_async yet.. Don't know the propose really

Comment: @Kets, it's all about queue. 'dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)' - code inside block will run in background and then, inside 'dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()' block we run label updating in main queue (not background).

Comment: What you should keep in mind is that you app have a main thread and the UI is never updated until the main thread has finished. dispatch_async creates another thread, (so the main thread isn't blocked). When the other thread has something to update in the UI it does it in the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
-(void)animate{
   ....
   for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [[cells detailLabel] setText: [[array objectAtIndex:index] returnRandomOptie]];
            });

            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.10];
            NSLog(@"%i", i);
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Nop doesn't work. Still the same, updates the label at the last cycle. Thanks for the thinking already!

Comment: This may be due to the time interval small. Check with `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0];`